# Footer backlink spam on Wordpress

Tags: seo, wordpress, backlinks, anchor

I created a blog for a friend of mine and decided to stick in a backlink to my website at the footer.

The issue is that there's about 15 pages over the past 2 weeks and I checked on majestic seo and it's telling me I've received over 20,000 backlinks in this time?

I'm wondering if it's an infected website generating spam somehow.

I had a search to see if anyone has this issue before I posted. I have since removed the backlink and awaiting to see a reduction but I'm just curious as to why it could be doing this?

I know people have positive and negative comments regarding footer backlinks but I'm just curious at this first of all.

Cheers,

Dev

Answer (score 3):

This isn't necessarily to do with backlinks from the friends blog. If you go into Google Webmaster Tools you will be able to get a list of the backlinks to your site. By using this data you will be able to see where the backlinks are coming from and if they are going to present you with an issue. If you are seeing an impossible amount from the friends blog then that could indicate that the blog has been infected and needs to be repaired to clean out the infection, but if the number of backlinks from the blog is correct then it will point you in other directions and show you where you need to look in order to identify if the backlinks in question are spammy backlinks or not.

Comment: I have found that Google is quite slow on displaying links in Search Console. With that in mind, you are absolutely correct. Cheers!!